# Unable to mount NTFS drive with RHEL 6

Tags: mount, ntfs, redhat-enterprise-linux

I installed RHEL 6 on my computer on the last drive with Windows XP. In RHEL 6 my drive has not been opened, it shows unable to mount NTFS file. So what can I do to resolve that?

Answer (score 4):

Install dkms and ntfs-3g from EPEL:

- For i386:

  ```
  rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm
  ```
- For x86_64:

  ```
  rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm
  ```

Then,

```
yum install dkms ntfs-3g
```

Comment: The provided link doesn't work in RH6.0 (beta), but after testing I found that this works: `http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm`

Answer (score 2):

The above answers did not work for me. Under Red Hat RHEL Server 6.3 (64 bit) to mount NTFS drives use the following commands:

```
wget http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
yum install ntfs-3g
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to say that under Red Hat Enterprise Workstation 6.1 (system patched on 2011-12-05) a combination of the above mentioned commands worked:

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm
yum install ntfs-3g
```

Of course, you need to su first, but this did the trick for me for accessing an NTFS formatted USB disk.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to install a few packages.

1. Execute these commands to install and configure the EPEL repository:

   ```
   wget http://epel.mirror.net.in/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
   rpm -Uvh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
   ```
2. Execute this command to install packages related to NTFS mount:

   ```
   yum -y install ntfs-3g ntfsprogs
   ```
3. Attach NTFS drive and mount the partition.