# Read NTFS partition on RHEL 5.8

Tags: ntfs, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have RHEL 5.8 64 bit, and NTFS partition on the same disk. How can I get access to this partition?

This answer [Unable to mount NTFS drive with RHEL 6](https://superuser.com/questions/251663/unable-to-mount-ntfs-drive-with-rhel-6) doesn't work for me:

```
[root@localhost alex]# rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm
Retrieving http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm
error: skipping http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm - transfer failed - Unknown or unexpected error
```

Comment: There is no host named `download.fedora.redhat.com` - the name server for `redhat.com` says NXDOMAIN (no such domain). I find it curious that RPM apparently does not handle this error case in any better way than failing with "transfer failed - Unknown or unexpected error". Surely it would be quite common for users to mistype URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run these with sudo or sudo su? So:

```
wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install ntfs-3g
```

or

```
wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
sudo su -
rpm -ivh epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
yum install ntfs-3g
```

Comment: Thanks, the first command succeeded. The second (rpm) gives the following error: rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64 How can I fix this?

Comment: Sorry, I included a link to a Red Hat 6.X version of the rpm, please see edited answer for corrected commands for Red Hat 5.X.

Comment: Thanks. Now, how can I find and mount this partition?

Comment: OK, solution is found.